# Azure Logic App: How to keep embedded image in email body when forwarding on?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am setting up a bulk emailing solution combining Logic Apps and SendGrid.

User sends email to a mailbox with attachment of required recipients > Logic App reads email > LA resends 'Body' via SendGrid for each recipient.

This works fine with a plain email. However, when an image is embedded within the body Outlook uses Content-IDs.

Currently the body of the email just says a broken image symbol.

How can the images be kept for the re-sending on?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCRuo.jpg)

Comment: Any update now? Or do you still have other problem?

Comment: Thanks George, that worked. (still working out how to reply on here) It's not 100% what I'm after though. So what's happening is that I'm trigger when an email is received into a mailbox using the Outlook O365 trigger. I'm then setting the body of the received email to a variable and then want to resend the body on using the SendGrid action. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't test with send grid, so I can say it won't work. However the [send mail(v3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sendgrid/#send-email-(v3)) with send grid body require html, so maybe you couldn't send it directly.

Comment: I've also tried using the normal Outlook O365 send mail action but get the same results. I've added a screenshot to the original post and here https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCRuo.jpg

Comment: Actually I have test the action, It's same because the body in the picture I pasted doesn't contain the picture information, so if you want to resend the mail you have to  extract the image contentbytes and send it.

Comment: Thanks George, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement it directly, it could be done. Because if you try to get the mail body you will find it's like below picture.

[image]

The body is escaped mail content and the image content is the contentBytes under attachments it's a base64 code.

So if you want to send a image from another mail you have to get the base64 code embed it to your mail. I use the outlook trigger to test it and send with sendgrid, the content will be like this code.

```
This is test email <br>\n<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,@{triggerBody()['attachments'][0]['contentBytes']}\">
```

[image]

[image]

I test this way could send the image, and it could be seen in the mail. If this is not what you want please let know.

Comment: Thanks George, that worked. (still working out how to reply on here) It's not 100% what I'm after though. So what's happening is that I'm trigger when an email is received into a mailbox using the Outlook O365 trigger. I'm then setting the body of the received email to a variable and then want to resend the body on using the SendGrid action. Does that make sense?